# why does my return statement return a null result?

Tags: spring, sftp

I am trying to connect to a distant machine and display some files from a specific directory.

The problem is when I test my function it returns a null result and what I want to do is to display file names.

Here is my code:

```
@Service
public class SftpClientImpl implements SftpClient {


    private LsEntry entry;

    @Override
    public LsEntry connectToServer() {
             String  SFTPHOST = "xxxxx";
             int   SFTPPORT = 22;
             String  SFTPUSER = "xxx";
             String  SFTPPASS = "xxxxx";
             String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/dir/dir2/dir3";

            Session session = null;
            Channel channel = null;
            ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

            try{
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
                session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
                java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(config);
                session.connect();
                channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                channel.connect();
                System.out.println("Starting the session ..");
                channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
                channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
                Vector filelist = channelSftp.ls(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
                for(int i=0; i<filelist.size();i++){
                    LsEntry entry = (LsEntry) filelist.get(i);
                    System.out.println(entry.getFilename());
                }
                while(session != null){
                    System.out.println("Killing the session");
                    session.disconnect();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return entry;
        } 
}
```

and:

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<LsEntry> getDirectories() {
        LsEntry entry = sftpClient.connectToServer();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entry, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: How do you call your end-point?

Comment: @RequestMapping("/log")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry` is null as it's value is only contained within the for loop, and is actually declared twice (once with private class scope, once with local scope within the for loop).

What I suggest is to correct your variable declaration and test the connection and filename printing. If it still doesn't work, try it within a known working spring endpoint. If it prints your directory as expected than move to its own endpoint and try again. In doing this it'll help narrow down the scope of your issue.

I've used the below code to connect to and print file names for the past few years and is heavily based on the example code provided by JSCH back then:

```
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  Session session;

  session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.setPassword(password);
  session.connect();

  Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
  channel.connect();
  ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

   //List our files within the directory
   Vector vv = sftpChannel.ls(srcDir);
   if (vv != null) {
       LOGGER.debug("We have a file listing!");
       for (int ii = 0; ii < vv.size(); ii++) {
           Object obj = vv.elementAt(ii);
           if (obj instanceof ChannelSftp.LsEntry) {
               LOGGER.debug("[" + ((ChannelSftp.LsEntry) obj).getFilename() + "]");

               if (ii < 1) { // empty directory contains entries for . and ..
                   continue;
               }

               String filename = ((ChannelSftp.LsEntry) obj).getFilename();
               filenames.add(filename);
               LOGGER.debug("filename is: {}", filename);
               ....
```

Comment: the thing is , i'm already connected to the server, and listed the files, but i've got the result only when i test it as a void method but what i really want is to return the list of the files so that i can display it in my User Interface

Comment: If you look at my method you can see I do the same thing :) `filenames` is an arraylist

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved my problem :) 
I corrected my variable declaration and it worked nicely, like you told me to :) thanks

```
@Override
public LsEntry connectToServer() {
    String HOST = "xxxxx";
         int  PORT = 22;
         String  USER = "xxx";
         String  PASS = "xxxxx";
         String DIR = "/dir/dir2/dir3";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    // LsEntry declaration 
    LsEntry entry = null;
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(USER, HOST, PORT);
        session.setPassword(PASS);
        // the rest of the code
        //....
        //...
        for (int i = 0; i < filelist.size(); i++) {
            //cast
            entry = (LsEntry) filelist.get(i);
            System.out.println(((LsEntry) entry).getFilename());
        }
        while (session != null) {
            System.out.println("Killing the session");
            session.disconnect();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (LsEntry) entry;
}
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i did it just to make sure that what i did is 100% true and to share my update :)

Comment: ah yeah i forgot to approve his answer , i will do it :)